# How do I draw arrows under equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations, text, polynom, polynomials

I don’t know how to produce the arrows circled in red:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Here is what I have so far:

```
\dfrac{5}{6} \div \left(-\dfrac{3}{4}\right)=\dfrac{5}{6} \times \left(-\dfrac{4}{3}\right)=-\dfac{10}{9}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about solving math problems rather than using latex as a typing engine.

Comment: I think it might be about how to typeset what they've handwritten, but I agree that it should be much clearer what they're wanting to do, and what they've already done.

Comment: Are you asking how to typeset equations like these? What are you having trouble with? The arrows underneath?

Comment: I think it is the arrows and text. They've asked another question about arrows and text as well.

Comment: @CroCo It's not a well-formed question, but it is about how to typeset what they've handwritten. See their other questions.

Comment: @CroCo Not to mention that other than #3, there's nothing to actually solve.

Comment: @Davislor I can't write these 4 equation. Help me

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: In my opinion, this was a good question that only appeared to be off-topic due to the use of ESL. There’s already an accepted answer, but I’ve edited the question for clarity and nominated it for reopening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By use of the `tikzmarknode` ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\[
\dfrac{5}{6} \tikzmarknode{a}{\div \left(-\dfrac{3}{4}\right)}
    = \dfrac{5}{6} \tikzmarknode{b}{\times \left(-\dfrac{4}{3}\right)}
    = -\dfrac{10}{9}
%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
overlay,remember picture,
transform canvas={yshift=-2pt}, cyan
                        ]
\draw [->] (a.south) -- ++ (0,-2mm) -| (b) node[pos=0.25, below] {text};
\draw   (a.south west) -- (a.south east)
        (b.south west) -- (b.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{1.5\baselineskip}   % reserves space for the image
\]
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

After two compilation you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @bayaraasurenjav, if answer solve your problem, you may accept it ;-)  (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer).